# Clojure beginner - implement flatten, trouble with 'let'

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

New to Clojure.

```
Input - ["a" ["b" "c"] "d"]
Expected output - ["a" "b" "c" "d"]
```

What I'm trying to do - create an empty vector ('result'), then do two doseq's on the input collection to fill 'result' up, finally return the filled up 'result'. However the function returns an empty vector. What am I doing wrong?

```
(flat ["a" ["b" "c"] "d"]) 

(defn flat [arr]
(let [result []]
     (doseq [element arr] 
            (if (coll? element) (doseq [element2 element] (conj result element2)) 
                (conj result element))) result))
```

Comment: `result` will always be bound to that empty vector - you never do anything to rebind `result` to anything else. One of the toughest things I've had to deal with when learning Clojure is that what are commonly thought of as "variables" are actually constants. You do call `conj` to add an element to `result`, but the return value from that `conj` call is then thrown away. `conj` doesn't modify its input collection - it creates a new collection which consists of the input collection plus the new element. Best of luck with Clojure - it will twist your brain, but you'll be better for it. :-)

Comment: `result` is immutable. It can never be changed. It isn't changing simply because you've called `conj` on it; `conj` returns the modified collection. You should be using `loop` or `reduce` here. `doseq` is the wrong choice in most cases like this.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question basically boils down to "how do I use immutable structures", which is quite broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you can't mutate result. If you really did want to implement your function with mutation you'd need an atom, which you can mutate with swap!

```
(defn flat [arr]
  (let [result (atom [])]
     (doseq [element arr] 
            (if (coll? element) (doseq [element2 element] (swap! result conj element2)) 
                (swap! result conj element)))
     @result))
```

Notice however, that this only gives you a single level of flattening, which you can accomplish simply with

```
(apply concat <your seq>)
```

A simple, recursive, multilevel flatten is:

```
(defn flat [x] (if (coll? x) (mapcat flat x) [x]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env boot

(def inp ["a" "b" ["c" "d" "e" ["f" "g" "h"] "i"] "j" "k"])

(defn flat 
  ([xs] (flat xs []))
  ([xs acc]
    (if (empty? xs) acc
      (if (vector? (first xs))
        (flat (rest xs) (flat (first xs) acc))
        (recur (rest xs) (conj acc (first xs)))))))

(println (flat inp))  ;[a b c d e f g h i j k]
```

The basic idea is to check if first element is a list, if so recurse that list `(flat (first xs) acc)` adding each element to the accumulator and then proceed with rest of the list giving `(flat (rest xs) (flat (first xs) acc))`. Else just recur individual elements.

We can use other constructs like `let`, `cond` as well.

Comment: Edited to added description.

Comment: coll? will return true for maps and sets which you usually don't want to flatten.  sequential? is probably a better choice.

Comment: If we need to flatten only vectors then we can use `vector?` check instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fast version of flatten, see clojure.core.reducers/flatten.

```
(require '[clojure.core.reducers :as r])
(defn rflatten [coll] (into [] (r/flatten coll)))
```